# Does anyone know how to permanently lock security key in MouseWithoutBorders app on windows 10/11?

Tags: security, mouse, kvm-switch, default-settings, microsoft

Does anyone know how to permanently set/lock security key in `MouseWithoutBorders` app on Windows 10/11?

It keeps on changing every time the pc reboots. I don't see anything in settings, or a command line options, or some other way to lock this down once for all.